# matplotlib in openSUSE

Tags: python, matplotlib, opensuse

I'm trying to use a python script under openSUSE. 
I did this script under ubuntu and it work well 
I have installed matplotlib and when I run the script it seems to work (I can do 
`print "It go until here"` at any place of the script it work.

But it never open the matplotlib windows....

**EDIT**

The shortest program that do not work is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=range(10)
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
```

I think the problem come from using matplotlib under openSUSE OS... but I do not understand exactly why .... there is no error message....

Comment: Apart from `alpha_slider` and `beta_slider` not being defined (which is not a big deal) the script runs fine. So the idea in such a case would be to create a [mcve] of the issue; i.e. what is the shortest program that still does not show a window upon calling `plt.show()`? Is e.g. `plt.plot([1,2,3]); plt.show()` working as expected?

Comment: Thanks , the problem is that any matplotlib window never appear... in any case... see **EDIT** in my post....

Comment: have you checked which backend is needed and if it is installed?

Comment: I didn't know about backend, I am reading about it on matplotlib website.

Comment: Maybe you remove the long code from the question and only keep the short one. Then add all the relevant information. Which python version, how did you install it, how did you install matplotlib, how do you run the script, etc. Concerning backend, try using "TkAgg", `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg"); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; #rest of code`.

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot !