# Plot doesn't show up in Python on OpenSUSE

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a given graph in Python, however, the graph doesn't show up at all. I use the following code:

```
import pylab as p

C = [1,2,3,4]
S = [10, 20, 30, 10]
p.plot(C,S)
p.show()
```

I suspect that it's because I use OpenSUSE with Wayland. Does anyone know a workaround, or how to plot in OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with Python?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was another post on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055078/matplotlib-in-opensuse), with a great answer from *ImportanceofBeingErnest*, suggesting to to use `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` **before** `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. You find more on [backends on the matplotlib site](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends).
You still may have to install the appropriate python-to-toolkit packages, eg. python-tkinter and python3-tk, or try an already installed backend. For example, **qt5agg**, provides an option to configure some graph parameters interactively.

Comment: This did it for me. It indeed seems important that `matplotlib.use()` is used before `pyplot` is imported.

Answer (score 0):

In Tumbleweed using Python 3.6

open Yast Software Management
select python3-matplotlib and I chose python3-matplotlib-tk as backend then install

This installs :-
python3-Cycler
python3-kiwisolver
python3-matplotlib
python3-matplotlib-tk
python3-numpy
python3-olefile
python3-Pillow
python3-python-dateutil
python3-pytz

In python script use :-
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Works for me.